# lmdb.open wont create new file

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, lmdb

I'm learning about deep learning and start to follow a tutorial.
At the frist part when I try to run:

```
train_lmdb = '~/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/input/train_lmdb'
validation_lmdb = '~/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/input/validation_lmdb'

train_data = [img for img in glob.glob("../input/train/*jpg")]
test_data = [img for img in glob.glob("../input/test1/*jpg")]

#Shuffle train_data
random.shuffle(train_data)

print 'Creating train_lmdb'

in_db = lmdb.open(train_lmdb, map_size=int(1e12))
```

I got the erro:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/input/train_lmdb'
```

lmdb.open was supposed to create the file, right? I dont understand why it its trying to open it.

Answer (score 0):

I just replace "~/" with "/home/user/" and it is working fine